# Excel COUNTIF Array (Multiple Criteria)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using this function:

```
=COUNTIF((B:B,"Superior")*(A:A,"Employee Effectiveness:"))= 2
```

The idea is to try and find how many times the value "Superior" is used adjacent to the cell with value "Employee Effectiveness:" and display that in a numerical value. Also want to repeat this function 3 more times.

**Format looks like:**

A1 - Employee Effectiveness:

B1 - Superior (or Good/Average/Below Average/Poor)

---

A2 - Response Time:

B2 - Superior (or Good/Average/Below Average/Poor)

---

A3 - Employee Courtesy:

B3 - Superior (or Good/Average/Below Average/Poor)

---

A4 - Expectations Met:

B4 - Exceeded (or Met/Below)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Countif in Excel with multiple criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/796139/countif-in-excel-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2007 or later versions you can use `COUNTIFS` function (with an "S" on the end) which lets you have multiple conditions for multiple columns, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,"Superior",A:A,"Employee Effectiveness:")`

Comment: This worked well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` as an alternative solution.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="Employee Effectiveness"),--(B:B="Superior"))
```