# Countif in Excel with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an index for law and order conditions in many countries over several years. For each country I want to find out how many countries are ahead and how many countries are behind for a given year. In the image attached below, I have tried to show what I want to do. I manually did the calculation for Albania (ALB). Out of total four countries in the sample, 3 countries were ahead of Albania in 1995 and none was below it. Similarly in 1996, 2 countries were above Albania and 1 country was below it. Same goes for 1997 and 1998.

Problem here is that I have 134 countries and 16 years. It will take me weeks to do it manually. I tried the following formula in MS Excel with no success:

`=IF($B:$B=B2,COUNTIF($C$2:$C$17,"<"&C2))`

Any ideas how I can do this? I am open to suggestions. I am simultaneously using MS Excel and Stata so any platform will work for me.

[image: Simplified example of my dataset and what I want to achieve]

Comment: This question seems off-topic for this site. Stack Overflow seems more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto Ferrer, I'll post it there as well. I am getting nice replies here so I'd like to keep this question here as well.

Comment: **Please, do not repost**. The question will probably be moved by administrators. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: You seem to have programming-oriented follow-up questions for every answer here. Exact reposting may be unwelcome, but I have [some advice on how to cross-post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2132/32036) more acceptably (between here and Math) that could help in your situation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way in Stata:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
country year law
1 1996 235
1 1997 25
1 1998 6445
2 1996 436
2 1997 2356
2 1998 224
3 1996 3129
3 1997 735
3 1998 836
end

list, sepby(country)

*----- what you want -----

sort year law
by year: gen ahead = _N - _n
by year: gen behind = _n - 1

sort country year
list, sepby(country)
```

Some assumptions are made, of course.

### Edit

The strategy is really simple. Sort the data by `year law`. The result is:

```
. list, sepby(year)

     +-----------------------+
     | country   year    law |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |       1   1996    235 |
  2. |       2   1996    436 |
  3. |       3   1996   3129 |
     |-----------------------|
  4. |       1   1997     25 |
  5. |       3   1997    735 |
  6. |       2   1997   2356 |
     |-----------------------|
  7. |       2   1998    224 |
  8. |       3   1998    836 |
  9. |       1   1998   6445 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Now we only need to realize that per each `year` group, the first observation (i.e. observations 1, 4, and 7) is outrun by two other observations (i.e. obs 1 is outrun by 2, 3; obs 4 is outrun by 5, 6; and obs 7 is outrun by 8, 9). This means that there are **two** observations that are `ahead` of observations 1, 4, 7.

Next, per each `year` group, the second observation (i.e. observations 2, 5, and 8) is outrun by one other observation. This means that there is **one** observation `ahead` of observations 2, 5, 8.

Finally, per each `year` group, the third observation (i.e. observations 3, 6, and 9) is outrun by zero other observations. This means that there are **zero** observations `ahead` of observations 3, 6, 9.

So now we see that after appropriately `sort`ing the data, per `year` group, we just need to create the sequence **two, one, zero**, for the `ahead` variable. This can be done in several ways. I chose to do it using subscripting (see `help subscripting`) and system variables `_n` and `_N` (see `help _variables`). `_N` is the total number of observations per group (3) and `_n` is the current observation per group. An example: for observation 1, the computation is `3-1 = 2`. For observation 2, it is `3-2 = 1`, and so on.

The `behind` variable is computed analogously.

The result is:

```
     +----------------------------------------+
     | country   year    law   ahead   behind |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |       1   1996    235       2        0 |
  2. |       2   1996    436       1        1 |
  3. |       3   1996   3129       0        2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  4. |       1   1997     25       2        0 |
  5. |       3   1997    735       1        1 |
  6. |       2   1997   2356       0        2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  7. |       2   1998    224       2        0 |
  8. |       3   1998    836       1        1 |
  9. |       1   1998   6445       0        2 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

In my code, after computing the new variables, I `sort` again just to present the data in its original sort order (`country year`).

Comment: this looks very promising. Can you walk me through these commands? 

sort year law
by year: gen ahead = _N - _n
by year: gen behind = _n - 1

thank you very much

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: genius!!! thanks alot. one last thing. you used sepby command. do i have to undo it afterwards or it doesnt affect other calculations?

Comment: `sepby()` is an option for a command. No need to "undo" it. It only affected the way data was displayed when `list` was issued.

Comment: understand... since first row contains variable names, ahead should be _N - _n -1 and behind should be _n -2 right?

Comment: No. In my example the "row" with variable names is not considered an observation. No need to take it into account. There could be a case in which observation 1 actually contains text that refers to the variable name, with subsequent observations containing the variable content. But that is not the case in my example. If it were your case, then an additional step would be needed to fix that.

Comment: great!! thanks alot.. best answer. exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

In Excel `COUNTIFS` (with an "S" on the end) can be used to count with multiple conditions, so try this formula in D2 copied down

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,">"&C2)`

For E2 just reverse the < to >

Answer (score 1):

Just sort by year and then apply the the formula 16 times - the formula may look like: `=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$13,">"&C2)` where 'C2-C13`is range of values for each year and`C2` is country (for the year) value that need to be compared to. I think it would not take long may be 1 minutes for country.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Ram. I was hoping for a concise way to do it without a need to manually setup the formula for each country (or each year). I need this because I dont have all variables yet and in future, I might have to repeat the procedure for many other variables.

Answer (score 0):

I use $i=1,...,n=164$ to count the countries, $t=1,...,16$ to count the years.

Denote $s_{it}$ the score of country $i$ in year $t$. Denote also $\alpha_{it}$ the number of countries that are ahead of cuntry $i$ in year $t$ and by $\beta_{it}$ the number of countries that are behind country $i$ in year $t$.

Obviously (assuming no ties, for which you will have to make a decision),

$$ \alpha_{it}+\beta_{it}= N-1,\;\; \forall t$$
The naive way:

**1)** Separate (in excel), the $16$ observations you have, obtaining $16$ cross-sectional series of $164$ cross-sections each. Keep the ID for each value in each of the $16$ vectors, in whatever way you have them (three-letter country ID, year)

**2)** Sort each of the $16$ vectors by magnitude, from *lowest* score to *highest* score 
**3)** To the right or left of each of the $16$ sorted vectors create the series ${1,2,3,...,164}$

So the lowest score $s_{it}$ is associated with the number $1$, and the highest with the number $164$.

**You have just ranked each country based on its score for each year**, denote the ranking $r_{it}$.

Then

$$\alpha_{it} = 164-r_{it},\;\;\; \beta_{it} = r_{it}-1 $$

How long do you think it's going to take you?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. You are right. I can do this easily for each cross section but I was hoping for a formula which can be used in the current data format. It is not because I am lazy, it is because I might have to repeat this procedure later for many other variables that I dont have yet.

Comment: The "current data format" appears to be well-suited for the above procedure (it is elementary to sort by year first). In any case, you have _not_ informed us of the fact that you require an input-output algorithm which can be applied more generally. On the contrary you _stressed_ the time-factor for the specific data set by exaggerating about it ("weeks") -and so I gave you a procedure that takes minutes. So please next time be more informative about what you really need, so that you can obtain the answers that can really help you.

Comment: It was not an exaggeration. I am not as efficient as you Alecos. I apologize for being unclear. Now that it is somehow clear what I need, can you guide me please?

Comment: It appears that the other two answers are closer to a more generally applicable algorithm, either in MS excel or in Stata. But anyway, in order to salvage the time spent already here, I will provide an even more efficient algorithm in a while, but in the same spirit, and for MS excel.