# Countif formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have dates in one column and names in the next column.

I want the formula to count the individuals as per the date. For example, on 10/1/2014, I want how many times the name Kiran is populated in the column the count

Below is the example

```
10/2/2014   Kiran
10/2/2014   Kiran
10/1/2014   Kiran
10/1/2014   Kiran
10/2/2014   Ajay
10/2/2014   Ajay
10/1/2014   Ajay
10/1/2014   Ajay
10/1/2014   Ajay
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel COUNTIF Array (Multiple Criteria)](http://superuser.com/questions/505765/excel-countif-array-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use COUNTIFS instead of COUNTIF